# bugs with two submit buttons in a single page

Tags: button, submit

I am a student doing a mini project Using [PHP](http://php.net).
In my administrator page I have a bug. i.e, First it Prompts for.

```
-->Hall ticket No 
-->Semester of the particular student.
```

Whenever admin enters these details and clicks firstsubmit button, it display the marks of particular student in textboxes.
If the marks are not available it displays empty text boxes, those allows the admin to insert the marks for that particular student.
After entering marks whenever he clicks second submit button, the marks have to be inserted in the database table.
**NOTE:** Marks and second submit buttons appear only when admin clicks first submit button by enetring Hallticketno and semester.
Bug is when I fill the text boxes with subjectwise marks and click second submit button
it is inserting '0's for all the subjects in the table Instead of entered marks in the textboxes.
 And here is my code:

```
<html>
         <body bgcolor="#abcdfg">
            <center><h2>WELCOME TO ADMINISTRATOR</H2>
                   <form name="admin" action="admin1.php" method="POST">
                  Hall Ticket No.:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" name="rno" value=""/>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                       Enter The Semister:
                    <input type="text" name="sem" value=""/>
                        <br>
                             <br>
                       <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Load the marks">
                          </form>


                     <?php
                  if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
                  {
                  $id=$_POST['rno'];
                  $semester=$_POST['sem'];
                  $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');


                           if (!$link) {
                                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                                 }


                $db_selected = mysql_select_db('etudient', $link);
                        if (!$db_selected) {
                               die ('Can\'t use etudient : ' . mysql_error());
                               }
  $sql='SELECT *
                               FROM `2-1`
                               WHERE id='."'".$id."'";
                               $result=mysql_query($sql);

                             if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)
                               {
                               echo 'marks were not entered for '.$id.' in '.$semester. ' semester'.'<br>'; 
                                    $empty='SELECT subname
                               FROM `2-1subjects`';


                               $eresult=mysql_query($empty);
                               if(!$eresult)
                        {
                        die('invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
                        }
                        Print "<table border=0 cellpadding=10>"; 
                        //Print "<th>SUBJECT CODE</th>";
                        Print "<th>SUBJECT NAME</th>";
                        Print "<th>MARKS</th>";
                        while($cow = mysql_fetch_array($eresult))
                                {
                                      Print "<tr>";
                                //Print "<td>".$row['subcode'] . "</td> ";
                                print "<td>".$cow['subname'] . "</td> ";
                                //Print "<td>".$row['marks'] . "</td> "; 
                                ?>
                                <form method="POST">
                            <td> <input type="text" name="mark" style="text-align:center" value=""/></td>
                            </form>
                                <?php
                                Print "</tr>";                              
                                   }
                                  Print "</table>"; 
                                  ?>

                                   <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Insert Marks"/>

                                   <?php
                                     if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
                                        {
                                          $insq='SELECT subcode
                                           FROM `2-1subjects`'; 
                                            if(!$insq)
                                          {
                                          die('invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
                                          }                                        

                                          $insre=mysql_query($insq);
                                          while($subrow=mysql_fetch_array($insre))
                                          {
                                          $mr=$_POST['mark'];
                                          $inser='INSERT into `2-1`(id,subcode,marks)
                                          VALUES('."'".$id."'".','
                                                  ."'".$subrow['subcode']."'".','
                                                  ."'".$mr."'".')';
                                          $inseresult=mysql_query($inser);
                                          if(!$inseresult)
                                          {
                                          die('invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
                                          }
                                          }
                                            echo "successfully Inserted.";

                                        }
                                        else{
                                        echo 'not submitted.';
                                        }

                                }



                               else
                               {
                               echo 'Marks Details of  '.$id.'   in  '.$semester.'  semester'.'<br>';
                               $query='SELECT subname,marks
                               FROM `2-1subjects`
                               JOIN `2-1`
                               ON `2-1subjects`.subcode=`2-1`.subcode
                               WHERE id='."'".$id."'";

                               $sql=mysql_query($query);
                               if(!$sql)
                        {
                        die('invalid Query:'.mysql_error());
                        }
                        Print "<table border=0 cellpadding=10>"; 
                        //Print "<th>SUBJECT CODE</th>";
                        Print "<th>SUBJECT NAME</th>";
                        Print "<th>MARKS</th>";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                                {
                                      Print "<tr>";
                                //Print "<td>".$row['subcode'] . "</td> ";
                                print "<td>".$row['subname'] . "</td> ";
                                //Print "<td>".$row['marks'] . "</td> "; 
                                ?>

                            <td> <input type="text" style="text-align:center" value="<?php echo $row['marks'] ?>" /></td>
                                <?php
                                Print "</tr>";                              
                                   }
                                  Print "</table>"; 
                                  print '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Marks"/>';
                                  }
```

and the values are being inserted in reverse order into the table that means bottom to top rather than that of which I entered at the time of inserting in textboxes.
please correct my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for a start you have spelling errors in your code. your sql query is defined as insre and you're calling it later as inser.

Comment: No actually the thing is $insre for storig the query result of query for subject code i.e.,subcode.                                            and $inser holds the query string for insert the marks into table. there are no spelling mistakes at all. So, don't get confused.

Comment: could anybody answer my question?